# What is the recommended Android HTTP Library for RESTFul JSON API interaction?

Tags: android, json, api, rest

I am a beginner in Android and I am currently trying to develop an app that interacts with a RESTful JSON API. After looking at several tutorials on the internet I am confused on exactly what library to use. I intend to have file uploads and video streaming in features in my app.

Comment: Sounds like you have already found many options. Pick one and try it – if it works and does what you want, use that one.

Comment: On a personal note, I prefer [Retrofit] https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the android developing team recommended using [`HttpUrlConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection) [for API level 9 and higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client). It was more efficient than Apache HTTP client because it reduced network use through transparent compression and response caching, and it minimized power consumption.

[Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) was also developed and introduced by Google during [Google I/O 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo) due to an absence in Android SDK, of a networking class capable of working without interfering with the user experience. However, it is important to note that **Volley is [not suitable for large downloads or streaming operations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/volley-library-in-android/)** since it holds all responses in memory during parsing.